# text-overflow works strange with centered text in Safari

Tags: html, css

Is this some kind of Safari bug?

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;padding:0 250px;text-align:center">
Skin-to-Skin Direct Look Cadaveric Training Program
</div>
```

**text-align:center**

[image]

**without text-align:center**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixes problem for me

```
<div style="padding:0 250px;">
  <div style="white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;text-align:center">
   Skin-to-Skin Direct Look Cadaveric Training Program
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the padding. If you remove it then it should work.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<div class="mydiv">
Skin-to-Skin Direct Look Cadaveric Training Program
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mydiv {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* padding: 0 250px;*/
    text-align:center;
    background-color: green;    
}
```

Shrieked : [image]

Wide : [image]

Comment: No, it's not. On both your screens container wider then text. The case is when container width less then text.

Comment: Try with this CSS :

.mydiv {
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align:center;
 background-color: green; 
}